# Console FTPS (not SFTP) client?

Tags: windows, ftp, ftps

I need to automate some transfers but it seems i can't find a decent command-line ftp client supporting FTPS for the windows platform? winscp supports SFTP but there's no good SFTP server for windows either, only FreeSSHDService which don't seems to be actively supported anymore.. therefore i want to use FileZilla Server which supports FTPS..

Comment: Do you need a FTPS or SFTP client? Those are very different things - FTPS is simple FTP+SSL, and SFTP is a separate protocol that uses SSH.

Comment: As stated both in title and in body I'm looking for a FTPS client, not a SFTP client from which there are many to choose from...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since i wrote the question WinSCP has been updated to support FTPS!

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps

Answer (score 6):

You could use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and select the <strike>openssh</strike> `lftp` package.

(It has a dependency to `openssl`, so I assume it was compiled using `configure --with-openssl`)

Comment: lftp is great, but cygwin is always such a hassle :(

Comment: Cygwin a hassle? Why? (I read in your profile *Works just as easily in windows servers as in a linux system*...?)

Answer (score 3):

The cURL library http://curl.haxx.se/ lists FTPS support in its list of features, so presumably the reference client provided with it can be used to make FTPS transfers from the command line.

On the point of "no good SFTP servers for Windows", cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) includes the full OpenSSH package, which comes with both

- a SSH server capable of allowing SFTP (or SCP) transfers
- a command-line sftp/scp client (called scp) which can be called from Windows scripts (batch files and WSH scripts via the shell.run method) - you just need to be careful to specify paths correctly.

I have used the SSH server provided by cygwin to provide SFTP/SCP support on several Windows systems. Thsi might be better to use instead of FTPS if only because FTPS is not as widely supported, as you have found.

Comment: seems ok, except you only can upload one file at a time.. i want to upload a folders without have to specify each filename..

Comment: True. You could try using the Windows "forfiles" command [a simple utility found in recent versions (you'll find it in the resource kits for older Windows releases) that does the basics of the "find" command you may be familiar with from Unix/Linux/BSD/cygwin] to run multiple calls curl for the files in a directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

[SFTPPlus](http://www.sftpplus.com/) has some automation features.

> Secure file transfer using Open
>   Standards (SSH, SFTP, FTPS, HTTP, PGP
>   etc) plus additional audit &
>   automation for enterprise strength
>   usage.

Comment: too bad you have to pay for it..

Answer (score 1):

if your going to automate transfers I would highly recommend going the SFTP route , using either WinSCP(free) or "CoreFTP client ($20)"  since those will support "scheduled" transfers.   FTPS clients "generally" dont support scheduled transfers although some GUI clients do support "queuing".

Answer (score 1):

C-Kermit contains a very good scriptable FTPS client.

The Windows version costs money, but not very much. Unix/Linux versions are free.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the SSHD`s haven`t seen an update in years because there really hasn't been much to add to these applications.

Personally i use http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/ for the server side and one of the putty clients for scripted sftp.

The website above mentions a new developer who's making some minor if nice changes, but as stated, i've never need anything beyond what was already there.

Your right there's not much in the way of ftps clients, it's the less loved of the two options, primarily due to the dual network port requirement, inconsistent character sets and different ways of listing dirs.

Cheers
M.

Comment: true, SFTP feels more solid, but i still think it's strange that there's hundreds of normal FTP clients but so few with FTPS support, when only need to wrap the FTP socket in a SSL tunnel..

Answer (score 0):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) has a nice SFTP client ([x86 EXE reference](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/x86/psftp.exe))
And, whatever you do, please use [public key authentication](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/putty-openssh.html).

---

I stand corrected; PuTTY uses [FTP tunneling through SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) which is different from your request for a [FTP through SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS).

Comment: A minor annoyance for those using client certificates to connect: PuTTY uses some proprietary format. (It does offer a free tool to convert standard certs into PuTTY certs, but it does take some extra effort to get it running.)

Comment: I agree, If you can use Cygwin, it would solve the problem any day. PuTTY is only if you choose to not use Cygwin on windows.

Comment: indeed PSFTP is a great SFTP client, but it isn't a FTPS client as i was asking for..

Comment: @Carl, My bad. I misread your need for a SSL FTP connection. Sorry for that.

Comment: Yep, Putty is pretty much a standard FTP client (and it supports regular non-ssl ftp) but the difference is that it connects on the telnet port 22 and it accepts a cert and it tunnels through into the ftp service on port 21.

Comment: @djangofan Maybe you figured this out by now but, putty is not an FTP client. It supports SFTP, which is basically an FTP/SSH hybrid protocol. Doesn't really work anything like FTP. Also, telnet is port 23. SSH is port 22.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CoreFTP](http://www.coreftp.com/)?  I checked it out a while ago - it does have a command line interface - but I ended up not using it (I had no requirement for command-line use).  Also, some features you have to pay for - but there is a free version.

Comment: ah, this could work.. but it doesn't give a feeling of a very solid application thou.. the command-line options are very limited and the GUI is kind of ugly..